# Free higher spin fields and gravity

Tags: gravity, field-theory, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, interactions, higher-spin

There are soft theorems that suggest that any massless boson with spin higher than 2 should be a free field theory and cannot have interactions. Does this mean that one cannot embed such fields into a theory with gravity, which naturally interacts with anything with a stress-energy?

Comment: This is an interesting question, put a bounty on it

Comment: the  usual Weinberg soft theorems are not enough: they  just say the couplings should go to zero as the momentum of the emitted high-spin goes to zero. To obey this is enough to couple the high-spin with several  derivatives for instance (and forces due to the exchanged of the massless high spin with thus decay faster than 1/r^2 ).  There are however other constraints and extensions that Porrati and others have found over time, see e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/0804.4672

Comment: @TwoBs thank you for the reference-- I'll have to give it a look. In the interim however it seems like you are describing nonminimal couplings between the higher-spin particles themselves, whereas the situation I am interested in is placing these particles in theories with gravitation. Here the form of the couplings is totally fixed by the graviton's universal coupling to the stress-energy tensor. My question is whether the soft theorems rule out this situation, even when you put no explicit coupling between the higher spin bosons in the theory.

Comment: @Panopticon  If you want to softly emit the graviton out a pair of higher spins you just get back the equivalence principle in its general form.  Instead, by emitting off-shell graviton at finite spacelike $q$, there is however Weinberg-Witten theorem that forbids the 2-tensor covariant energy-momentum $T_{\mu\nu}$ for the higher spins. The loophole is however that $T_{\mu\nu}$ needs not to be covariant though. This loophole is precisely what was closed by Porrati, who provided an extension of Weinberg-Witten and derived a very robust inconsistency of massless higher spins in flat spacetime.

Comment: @TwoBs thank you for your response! If you make this an answer I will accept it.

Comment: @Panopticon  naahh, too much work to write a complete answer. I am ok if someone else edit it into one though,  e.g. from expanding  a bit this comment above. All the best

Answer (score -3):

When you have a higher spin field, it will, in principle, have a stress-energy tensor, and since gravity couples to the stress-energy tensor, it should follow that gravity will naturally couple to this field.

### The Question

You clarified your question in a comment, I will highlight below:

> "My question is whether the soft theorems rule out [the] situation [of the form of the couplings is totally fixed by the graviton's universal coupling to the stress-energy tensor], even when you put no explicit coupling between the higher spin bosons in the theory."

Simply put, can we predict or explain if gravity fails to interact with other fields even when no explicit coupling is introduced? And, do the soft theorems rule out interactions even if there's no explicit coupling introduced?

### My answer

While soft theorems don't rule out interactions entirely, they place strict constraints on their form and strength. So, while you might not introduce a direct coupling, it must be remembered that the dynamics of the theory, especially in the context of gravity, can lead to *emergent* interactions that must still obey these constraints.